# Como posso passar um valor de uma classe para uma Listbox

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, winforms, classes

Estou envolvido num pequeno projecto pessoal, composto por algumas classes e muitas forms. Necessito de enviar um valor que é obtido quando acedo a determinado botão, para a listbox que está numa dessas forms. Para isso optei por construir um método chamado **beverageclick** com o seguinte código

```
 public void beverageclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;//button sender

        string value = (string)b.Tag;// value = b.tag (tag of sended button tag = value (value of  AddBeverageDrinkstoTabbedPanel) method)
        beverages.Add(value);
        //get value


        //MessageBox.Show(value);
        ListBox lstbox = new ListBox();
        lstbox.Items.Add(value);



        }
```

Como posso alterar o código acima indicado por forma a que ao aceder a um botão, o valor desse botão (texto) seja inserido na listbox.

Comment: Aparentemente o problema aqui é que você está criando uma nova instância de `ListBox` que não é aquela que você incluiu no seu form.

Answer (score 2):

Voce está criando uma ListBox toda fez que este botão for clicado. Adicione esse valor numa listbox previamente criada, tire `ListBox lstbox = new ListBox();`. Mas se você deseja criar uma ListBox toda vez que o evento for acionado não se esqueça de colocar essa listBox em um painel ou algo do tipo.